# update 2d histogram with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics

I wrote a function to update a 2D histogram and it is not as fast as I would hope,

Is there any way to make this code more efficient with numpy:

```
def histadd(histogram, update):
    for i in range(len(update)):
        for j in range(len(update[0])):
            histogram[i][j][update[i][j]]+=1
    return histogram
```

where histogram is an MxNx256 array and update is an MxN array of integers ranging from 0 to 255 inclusive.

Comment: Something not clear here. You have an "update" parameter, what is not used eventually, because the dimensions of it are used, but they are same as 2 dimensions of histogram. You use "new" but it is not a parameter. Maybe "new" should be "update" ?

Comment: Oh, that's my bad new is supposed to be update, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no faster way to do that.
It is possible to write it shorter, but it is slower than your version:

```
def histadd(histogram, update):
    for a,b in np.ndindex(update.shape):
        histogram[a,b,update[a,b]]+=1
    return histogram
```